# Can Kibana reports be designed similarly to Sentry Error Logging?

Tags: logging, kibana, sentry, bug-tracking, dynamic-analysis

Can the reporting functionality in Kibana be used to design reports that works similarly to how Sentry provides reports to developers? I do believe that some more things need to be in place. For instance full stack trace need to be added in the log files sent to Kibana.

The main reason for the question is to avoid having both Sentry and Kibana in same technical domain, when Kibana is already present and fully functioning.

Comment: Yes through a (free open source) product called elastic apm